# Codeigniter upload helper - is_image returns false.

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am trying to upload images.  My code is exactly like the documentation in codeigniter but when I var_dump `die(var_dump($this->upload->data('')));` I get the following:

(array) [14 elements]
file_name: (string) 
file_type: (string) 
file_path: (string) 
full_path: (string) 
raw_name: (string) 
orig_name: (string) 
client_name: (string) 
file_ext: (string) 
file_size: (null) NULL
is_image: (boolean) false 
image_width: (null) NULL
image_height: (null) NULL
image_type: (string) 
image_size_str: (string)

Controller:

```
    public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']             = '8192';
    $config['max_width']            = 0;
    $config['max_height']           = 0;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    die(var_dump($this->upload->data('')));
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php if (isset($error)) : echo $error; endif?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/user_authentication/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

I have tried fixing the upload path but the same dump is returned.

Comment: Update:  It might be a windows issue.  I cant switch off the read only function on the uploads folder.  When I uncheck the box it just reappears.  I gave myself full control but it keeps on happening.

Comment: Disregard the comment, if it was read-only then sublime text would not be able to make changes to the folder.  So I do not think that is the issue.

Comment: Update:  I have no idea why but the var_dump is returning the data now.  The only thing I did was use the path helper to see what the path is that I set.  However, I think it has to be an issue with the path because when I remove the . in front of "./assets/uploads/" the data fails to return.  It might have been the windows issue as well. I will post my code again for reference.

Comment: why you dump before 'do_upload' function? it should output like that anyway. I suggest editing, giving ease to the reader.